# Space between TextView in android spinner

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, material-design

I'm trying to set margin for the textView inside the spinner. But setting margin inside the textView doesn't seem to work.

*tv_entity.xml*

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tvListEntity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/item_search_list"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="40dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:text="@string/enter_email"
    android:textColor="@color/search"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:drawableRightCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_24"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_goneMarginTop="20dp" />
```

Setting the adpater :-

```
  val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(),R.layout.tv_entity,arrayList)
```

[image]

I basically need some space on the left,right and top of the textView.

Answer (score 0):

Replace android:layout_height="40dp" by android:layout_height="wrap_content" and app:layout_goneMarginTop="20dp" by android:paddingTop="20dp"